# number_to_currency issue 100{:separator=>",", :delimiter=>".", :raise=>true}000

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization

I stumbled upon a quite annoying problem while using i18n.

When using `<%= number_to_currency("100000000.123456") %>`

I am getting on the screen:

`100{:separator=>",", :delimiter=>".", :raise=>true}000{:separator=>",", :delimiter=>".", :raise=>true}000 €`

HERE my locale yml:

```
number:
  currency:
    format:
      unit: "&euro;"
      precision: 0
      separator: " "
      delimiter: "."
      format: "%n&nbsp;%u"
```

I was using Rails 3.0.0rc, I have now upgraded to 3.0.9 the issue remains.

As suggested I removed format: "%n %u" from the locale file but the problem remains.

I am using i18n 0.5.0

Hope you can help

Comment: If you temporarily remove the number format options from your locale, do you still have the same problem? (This could help narrow it down to either a locale issue, or a bug with number_to_currency).

Comment: removing the number format doesn't resolve. I still have the problem. What do you reckon I should try next? in the meantime I did upgrade to  3.0.9 and I still have the issue. I may try downgrading i18n. cheers

Comment: I found a workaround for now. I copied the number helpers from actionpack 2.2.2 into my ApplicationHelper and prefixed them with my_ and now it works??? I had also added gem actionpack, '~>3.0.9' in my gemfile but that didn't help ... I am not happy with my work around so let me know if you have a clue about what I may have done wrong. Cheers.

Comment: 1) What is the name of your locale `.yml` file and what is the path relative to the root of the rails app? I mean is it in `config/locales/` or in another folder? 2) Is that exactly how your `yml` file looks like, because you need at the top to have the language namespace? 3) From `/config/application.rb` can you copy all the uncommented lines that contain this part:`:locale`? Can you do the same for the environment configuration file that you are trying this (e.g. if you're trying in development copy the ones from `config/environments/development.rb`)

Comment: Does calling `to_f` on the string help? `<%= number_to_currency("100000000.123456".to_f) %>`

Answer (score 0):

When i run it from the Rails console, i get:

```
Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.8)
1.9.3p194 :001 > include ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper
 => Object 
1.9.3p194 :002 > number_to_currency('10000.45')
 => "EUR  XXX 10.000,45" 
1.9.3p194 :003 >
```

Replacing with HTML entities works fine.

My en.yml (./config/locales). Make sure you indent **correctly**.

```
en:
  hello: "Hello world"

  number:
      currency:
          format:
            unit: "EUR "
            precision: 2
            separator: ","
            delimiter: "."
            format: "%u XXX %n"
```